# How to Programatically cancel order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, programmatically, cancel-orders

If a customer placed an order of 3 different items with different quantities like

1. shirt 2 qty
2. Watch 1qty
3. pant 3qty

and cancels the order item at different times I have to set the state to order cancelled

here's my code can anyone please tell me where I am wrong

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
         $_orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');

     $collection = $_orderCollectionFactory->create()

             ->addFieldToSelect('*')
             ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'cancelled']); 
foreach ($collectionFactory as $order)
        {
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($items as $items) {

                $totalitem = $totalitem + ($item['qty_canceled']);
                $itemcount = $order->getQtyOrdered();
               if ($itemcount == ($totalitem))
                 {
                    $order->setState("canceled");
                    $order->save();
                }

            }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have Solved the issue for the above code

$_orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');

```
 $collection = $_orderCollectionFactory->create()
         ->addFieldToSelect('*')
         ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['neq' => 'cancelled']);
```

foreach ($collection as $order)
{

```
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $totalitem=0;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
             $totalitem = $totalitem + ($item['qty_canceled']);
            $itemcount = $order->getQtyOrdered();

            if ($itemcount == ($totalitem))
             {
                echo $order->getIncrementId();
                $order->setState("canceled");
                $order->setStatus("canceled");
                $order->save();
             }
        }    
}
```